Disabling autocompletions in gud-gdb
I'm debugging a large C/C++ project (several millions lines of code, adding debug symbols to exec make it grow by 2.5Go) using GUD (gdb 12.1) on Emacs 29.1.
My issue is that in the gud-<my_exec_name> buffer, when I want to introduce a breakpoint, I experience severe lags due to autocompletions attempts.
At first I tried to disable company-mode by adding (global-company-mode '(not gud-mode)) in my init.el file, but the issue remains and it looks like company is still being used in the background. It forces me to spam C-g when working on the debugger.
I've ran a gdb session using the built-in emacs profiler and indeed, the main cpu user is company-calculate-candidates (80% of the runtime).
How can I stop emacs from trying to autocomplete in this buffer ?
(My other remaining active minor modes in this buffer are Helm, Anzu, VHl and Undo-Tree)
Edit, adding info as requested in a comment: the config I use on my project is the following:
OS is a linux (tested on CentOS 7 and AlmaLinux 8.4), the machines are rather large ones (40 cores, 1TB RAM).
I use gtags to tag the code base (gtags 6.6.3, ). The whole make process happens outside emacs. I normally use eglot with clangd for my cc-mode but the problem keeps happening when deactivating it. No irony, ccls or lsp-mode. Allowing queries of debuginfod servers has no influence neither.
The problem does not occur when running a bare emacs (empty init.el).
Here is a small curated init.el where the problem happens:
(require 'cc-mode)
(use-package cc-mode
  :init
  (define-key c-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete)
  (define-key c++-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete))

(use-package company
  :init
  (global-company-mode 1)
  (delete 'company-semantic company-backends))


(use-package company-c-headers
  :init
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-c-headers))

(require 'eglot)
(add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs '((c++-mode c-mode) "clangd"))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)

(setq gud-gdb-command-name gdb --annotate=1 -i=mi --args <my_exec>)
(setq
  gdb-many-windows t
  gdb-show-main t)
(global-company-mode '(not gud-mode))



Update your question with info about your OS and what tools/packages pertaining to cc-mode
are used for your project: /rtags/irony/make/cmake/eglot/lsp/clang/ccls,
since, as you observed, partially blocking company does not help, so
there must be something else generating the unwanted behavior.

@Ian, I've updated my question with more informations about my configuration, as well as with a minimal ìnit.el`that reproduces the problem.

Have you tried commenting out each section of the above init file and see if anything changes? In particular, commenting out all the company stuff? Have you tried toggling on debug-on-quit and then doing C-g during a time when it seems to be hanging? That should give you a backtrace and (if you are lucky) will point you directly at who's spinning - even if you are unlucky, there should be a hint in the backtrace.

From your code snippet I can observe clangd is not used correctly, there are
some command line arguments that must be passed to get useful results. These
are as follow:

--background-index: if omitted, clangd try to index a limited number
of symbols in memory (RAM), and if not found some symbol at one moment, it try
to re-index, so time consuming. If specified, it index the project in two parts,
the system include files in home folder and project symbols in
<project-folder>/cache/clangd/index/. If you have ggtags then there
is another time consuming job and which one is the first is not clear.
clangd limits the number of returned results to prevent UI freezes by
default. If you have more than a 1000 symbols and you would like to get
through all of them, please pass --limit-references=0 to clangd invocation.
You can speed up indexing/searching by using several parallel jobs, with
the argument -j=10, where 10 is supposed to be the number of idle
cores available (I use 4 on my machine with 10 cores).

I use lsp-mode to configure the above - (maybe eglot support them
also, but I do not use it) - this way:
(setq lsp-clients-clangd-args '("-j=4"
                                "--background-index"
                                "--limit-references=0"
                                "--clang-tidy"
                                "-log=error"))

Please note the clangd indexing takes place if you have a database - that
is obtained using CMake and the file CMakeLists.txt, which describe
your project. Note that database is not compatible with ggtags
(maybe it is useful to avoid ggtags, and do not use it with clangd).
A sample/small exmple of CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.15)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17")
include_directories("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1")
include_directories("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include")
# if you have a projname.h file, uncomment the line below.
# include_directories("/Users/your-name/abs-path-to your-proj-root")

project (projname)
set (projname_SRCS projname.cpp)
add_executable(projname ${projname_SRCS})

Now, to generate the database, we need to give CMake the following command,
always in project root:
cmake -G Ninja -Bbuild -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++

And to compile/build the project, use the command (modified emacs compile)
cd build && ninja -j 10

Note the package company-c-headers is not needed with clangd and CMake.
If this will be still slow, then maybe it is wise to check/use a second tool
(IDE/PDE) to see the results. Anyway, clang/clangd works better with CMake,
and the database will be needed. As for debugger, try dap-debug (lsp install
this by default).

Thanks a lot for those feedbacks. I'll try them today (the compile chain is non trivial so it's going to take a little while) and will give you feedback on the effect on my project.
